# Ruby: How to set the RubyGems UserAgent?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, user-agent

This could be a SuperUser question, but the RubyGems help said to ask it here.

I'm curious what Ruby uses for its UserAgent when downloading gems and how, if possible, to set it - either through the config, Ruby script, or an environment setting?

Answer (score 2):

To see how the Rubygems' user agent is set on your system:

```
require 'rubygems/remote_fetcher'
Gem::RemoteFetcher.new.user_agent
# => RubyGems/2.0.3 x86_64-linux Ruby/2.0.0 (2013-05-14 patchlevel 195)
```

It is not intedend to be customized. It is set on the creation of a `Gem::RemoteFetcher` object, which is instantiated by each command that need to fetch gem files from the net. The only way I see to change it is to hack Rubygems. For more information see `rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb`.

Comment: very helpful, I'll see if simply setting it there will be enough, though if RubyGems or RVM uses the UA to determine the correct gem, I could see this being problematic, unless I could inflate the UA and concatenate more than one string.